# Wordpress database connection error...looking for old username?

Tags: wordpress

I migrated this website a while ago of azure hosting on to normal hosting. I believe it has been working for a while but now, it's having a database connection error. All the database details are correct. But if I go to /wp-admin, it is saying a different username (old username on azure) is unable to connect to the database. however in wp.config it's not even listed.

Can this username be entered anywhere else for it to go through?

Comment: Just for future reference, if you are migrating a WP site again you're better to use a plugin like [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) - it makes sure everything gets migrated & updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

1. The login details and the site URL are fetched from the database in wordpress.

You need to update your URL to load the admin section of the website. You may use these queries:

Update queries for wordpress hosting shift:

*UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');*

2. If you have root access to the database server, update the password unsing MD5 encryption.

   3. Once you are able to login to the admin section, update the permalinks in the setting>permalinks.